# Load UIWebView in UITableViewCell and Make UITabViewCell's height as per the content of UIWebview

Tags: uitableview, uiwebview

I am working on a project, where I have a UITableViewCell containing UIImageView, UILable and UIWebView. 
I need to open a webview (with added HTML string in it) on didselectrowatIndexpathmethod and cell height should be increase to the content size of UIWebView. I have tried following code. But this is not working as per the expectation. Kindly advice.

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [faqContentArray count];
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     FAQCell *cell = (FAQCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.faqContentWebView loadHTMLString:[[faqContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"content"] baseURL:nil];
    NSString *wrappedText = [[faqContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"content"];
    cell.faqContentWebView.frame=CGRectMake(8.0f, 43.0f, 304.0f, [self minHeightForText:wrappedText]);


    [self rotateIconToExpanded:cell.faqImage];
     [self.faqTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
}
//-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//     FAQCell *cell = (FAQCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//    
//    [cell.faqContentWebView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
//    cell.faqContentWebView.frame=CGRectMake(8.0f, 43.0f, 304.0f, 5);
//    [self rotateIconToCollapsed:cell.faqImage];
//     [self.faqTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
//}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FAQCell *cell = (FAQCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    if (!cell) {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FAQCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
        cell = (FAQCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
     }



    cell.faqContentWebView.delegate=self;
    cell.faqContentWebView.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
    cell.faqContentWebView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    cell.faqContentWebView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    cell.faqContentWebView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    cell.faqContentWebView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
    cell.faqContentWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    cell.faqContentWebView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    cell.faqContentWebView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    cell.faqTitleLbl.text=[[faqContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.faqImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"downarow.png"];

    return cell;
}
- (void)rotateIconToExpanded:(UIImageView *)iconImage {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotateDisclosure" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    iconImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 2.5);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)rotateIconToCollapsed:(UIImageView *)iconImage {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotateDisclosure" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    iconImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 2);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    id celll = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    FAQCell *cell=(FAQCell *)celll;
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    NSLog(@"height------>%f",[cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height);
    return [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to calculate (and possibly monitor) the size of your content in the `UIWebView`. One way is through `UIWebView`'s `UIScrollView`:

```
CGFloat webViewContentHeight = myWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
```

another is:

```
CGFloat webViewContentHeight = [myWebView stringForEvaluatingJavaScript:@"document.body.offsetHeight"].floatValue;
```

When you retrieve that height is important, you will want it once the content of the `UIWebView` has finished loading (once it has you can invalidate/update the constraints of your `UITableViewCell`, for example).